# error on changing to device mode, Already have a Dart type associated

Tags: dart, dart-polymer, polymer-1.0, dartium

I have a dart-polymer project working just fine in dartium. When changing to device mode/responsive design mode it throws multiple errors of the first type, I have removed some of them:

```
Already have a Dart type associated with paper-material interop_support.js:72 registerDartTypeUpgrader
interop_support.js:72 Already have a Dart type associated with paper-ripple
...
interop_support.js:72 Already have a Dart type associated with iron-request
...
interop_support.js:72 Already have a Dart type associated with neon-animatable
...
interop_support.js:72 Already have a Dart type associated with slide-from-right-animation
...
interop_support.js:72 Already have a Dart type associated with google-map
interop_support.js:72 Already have a Dart type associated with array-selector
interop_support.js:72 Already have a Dart type associated with dom-bind
...
undefined:1 Exception: Uncaught Error: NotSupportedError: Failed to execute 'registerElement' on 'Document': Registration failed for type 'resultat-element'. A type with that name is already registered.
Stack Trace:
#0      JsObject._callMethod (dart:js:235)
#1      JsObject.callMethod (dart:js:225)
#2      PolymerRegister.initialize (package:polymer/src/common/polymer_register.dart:19:23)
#3      loadInitializers.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:initialize/src/static_loader.dart:46:42)
#4      _runInitQueue (package:initialize/initialize.dart:35:24)
#5      _runInitQueue.<anonymous closure> (package:initialize/initialize.dart:38:39)
#6      _RootZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1155)
#7      _Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:484)
#8      _Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:567)
#9      _Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:358)
#10     _Future._asyncComplete.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future_impl.dart:412)
#11     _asyncRunCallbackLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:41)
#12     _asyncRunCallback (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:48)
#13     _handleMutation (dart:html:42316)
```

I can see one other also had a problem in an earlier version of polymer-dart [here](https://github.com/dart-lang/polymer-dart/issues/58).

My .yaml file is looking like this

```
environment:
  sdk: '>=1.0.0 <2.0.0'

dependencies:
  web_components: '>=0.11.3 <0.13.0'
  route_hierarchical: any
  reflectable: ^0.3.1
  sqljocky: any

dependency_overrides:
  polymer:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/dart-lang/polymer-dart.git
      ref: 1.0.0-rc.2
  polymer_interop:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/dart-lang/polymer_interop.git
      ref: 1.0.0-rc.1
  polymer_elements:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/dart-lang/polymer_elements.git
      ref: update

transformers:
- web_components:
    entry_points:
      - web/index.html
- reflectable:
    entry_points:
      - web/index.dart
```

I have tried looking at the different git issiues polymer_interop, polymer_elements and [polymer-dart](https://github.com/dart-lang/polymer-dart/issues). But cant figure out what the problem can be and hot to fix it. Maybe it is a bug in one of the early releases I am using.

Comment: I have also looked at the issiue trackers for [polymer_interop](https://github.com/dart-lang/polymer_interop/issues) and [polymer_elements](https://github.com/dart-lang/polymer_elements/issues)

Comment: You shouldn't need the dependency_overrides anymore. Can you please try again without.

Comment: It would also be interesting if you also get the error in Chrome (instead of Dartium)

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer thanks, I tryed to remove the dependency_overrides, it resulted in updates on both polymer to rc.3 and polymer_interop to rc.2, but still get the errors in dartium, but don't get them in chromium.

Comment: Can you share an entire (minimal) project that allows to reproduce the problem on GitHub? What Dart version are you using?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I have made a gitHub repo [here](https://github.com/cbobach/nightTrail-dart-v2). I am using dart version 1.13.0-dev.7.2

Comment: the published polymer_elements seem to be as current as the git branched referenced in your pubspec.yaml.

Comment: You don't need to add Dart script tags to your elements `<dom-module>` if you use `@HtmlImport()`

Comment: See also https://github.com/dart-lang/polymer-dart/issues/58

Comment: Not related to the issue: The `<style>` tag should be inside the `<template>` tag (not sure if you have it outside for a specific reason or because it was mandatory in Polymer.js in the past) this changed (again) a while ago.

Comment: I suggest you clean up your project to make a minimal reproducible example (try to remove as much as possible that's not necessary to reproduce the problem)  and create a bug report in github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues.

Comment: I forgot to mention, I can reproduce on Dartium from bleeding_edge, also after I applied the changes I mentioned above.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Thank you, i will make the changes and see if i can reproduce the problem in a simpler form.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Now i have striped it down and the error is still there, you can try it [here](https://github.com/cbobach/spa_error). I am filing the bug as you mentioned [here](https://github.com/dart-lang/polymer-dart/issues/58)

Comment: I have created a bug report [here](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/24702)